# How to keep eclipse from wrapping multiline comments /*...*/ in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, comments

How do I keep eclipse from wrapping multiline comments in Java when using /* ... */?

For example, Eclipse will take this:

```
/*
// Old code, don't use
for( int i = 0; i < myarray.length(); i++){
        myarray[i].haveFun();
}
*/
```

And turn it into this:

```
/*
// Old code, don't use for( int i = 0; i <  
myarray.length(); i++){  myarray[i].haveFun();
}
*/
```

Comment: What language is this? The formatter capabilities vary a lot between different languages.

Comment: Sorry, the language is Java

Comment: Why do you need the single line comment inside a multiline one?

Comment: Eclipse's formatter can be configured, but your given example is ZOMBIE CODE which hurts you and your fellow developers. Do a good thing, remove zombie code comments altogether: http://www.bitnative.com/2012/10/22/kill-the-zombies-in-your-code/

Comment: Great point about zombie, but it doesn't fit my situation where I am trying out different blocks of code to see which one I want.

Comment: Question here is - why on earth would you leave commented code like this? Just delete it, commit to SCM with informative message and if You ever want to get back to it, just compare revisions.

Comment: If you have multiple blocks of code and you really want to pick and choose between them at any moment, you should put them in their own methods/functions. You can choose which one to call, the others don't have to be commented in/out, and Eclipse can remind you which ones aren't called anywhere. Once you've decided which variant you prefer, you can delete the others and not have any zombie code to haunt you.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse formatter -> "Off/On Tags" -> Enable.
Then use comments, for example:

```
// @formatter:off
...
// @formatter:on
```

Comment: But it would be better to remove the comments. You are using version control system, right? :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter` and select `Edit...` on the active profile.

Switch to the `Comments` tab and enter a large value for the `Maximum line width for comments` value

Comment: This IMO is better than disabling the formatter completely.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Format-Settings-in-Eclipse

The article explains how to do exactly what you want and more.